# In a doped semiconductor does the Fermi level increase or decrease with increasing/decreasing temperature?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

As we all know the Fermi energy level is $E_\mathrm{f}$ and from statistical mechanics we know that the Fermi level for $T>0\;\mathrm{K}$ the level remains almost constant.It changes fro $E_\mathrm{f}$  to 0.9997$E_\mathrm{f}$  when the material is put to almost its melting temperature. (see ascroft mermin's solid state physics book for the referance)

But in semiconductors we are familiar with a formula i.e $E_\mathrm{f}=E_\mathrm{c}-k_\mathrm{B}T\ln(N_\mathrm{c}/n)$ (for n type) which tells us that the ***Fermi level changes even with small fluctuations in temperature*** and this conflicts with the before said statement.

Can anyone explain the difference?

Comment: https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.1629090 would be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks but that paper  does not answer my exact doubt ,rather it assumes that the fermi level changes in a semionductor but why when it should not vhange as per FD distribution and sommerfields expresssion

Comment: Fair enough. Sze covers it well in his first chapter, as do other semiconductor physics books. The bottom line is that the Fermi level is a function of  temperature and impurity concentration. This may seem a bit non-intuitive, but remember that Fermi level changes to ensure charge neutrality, so as more electrons go into the conduction band it must move.

Comment: Pro Tip: Use MathJax and get rid of all the exclamation points.

Comment: @JonCuster Yes I got this point while reading any  semiconductor book  but the doubt comes when i see that to change fermi energy from E_f to 0.9997E_f i have to go to the melting temperature.